# How would I find where a function originates in source code?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble actually following the source code, mostly because simply using grep on it isn't working.

Is there any way to find out from which class a certain method was inherited? For example, if there is class `A`, which has method `foo()` and `bar()`, and there is class `B` which has `biz()`, and class `C` which inherits all of it's attributes and methods from both `A` and `B`, how would I be able to determine which class `foo()` came from (without strictly looking at the source manually)?

Comment: What text editor are you using? I would recommend using a proper IDE that hyperlinks you from a usage to a definition of a class

Comment: I'm just using gedit; but I tried using Visual Studio on my Windows machine and it was still unable to find it.

Comment: I would recommend using PyCharm - you can get the pro version for free if you are a student. Otherwise, you could try eclipse with the pydev plugin. [Here's a list of python IDEs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/198633)

Comment: Or, look into [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) with [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) for a more light-weight solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always access the super-classes of a class by looking in the **[`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__)** attribute for that class. Given three simple classes `A`, `B`, `C` (which for `Py2.7` ***must*** inherit from `object`) :

```
class A: 
    def foo():
        pass
    def bar(): 
        pass    

class B:
    def biz(): pass

class C(A, B):
    pass
```

You can then iterate through the **[`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__)** for `C` and check whether an attribute, function `foo` (for example), exists in one of these classes.

To do this you can check for membership of `foo` in the **[`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)** that holds the names for each class object in `__bases__`:

```
for base in C.__bases__: 
    if 'foo' in base.__dict__: 
        print("Attribute: '{}' defined in {}".format("foo", base))
```

Which prints:

```
Attribute: 'foo' defined in <class '__main__.A'>
```

---

*For a more complete and general view:*

```
# get all attributes of class C
vars = [classVar for classVar in dir(C) if not classVar.startswith('__')]

# iterate through all bases:
for base in C.__bases__: 
    for attr in vars:
        if attr in base.__dict__:
            print("Attribute: '{}' defined in {}".format(attr, base))
```

Which returns:

```
Attribute: 'bar' defined in <class '__main__.A'>
Attribute: 'foo' defined in <class '__main__.A'>
Attribute: 'biz' defined in <class '__main__.B'>
```

---

For **all** classes in the chain of inheritance  you can switch `__bases__` to [**`__mro__`**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) which indicates the method resolution order; a tuple of objects python searches when trying to resolve attribute references.

If we add a function to class `C` and make another class `D` that inherits from `C`:

```
class C(A, B): 
    def another(): pass

class D(C): pass
```

To get a view of where each function is defined, just switch `__bases__` with `__mro__` in the loop:

```
# hold D's attributes (functions names, variables.)
attrs = [var for var in dir(D) if not var.startswith('__')]
# vars contents: ['another', 'bar', 'biz', 'foo']

for base in D.__mro__: 
    for attr in attrs:    
        if attr in base.__dict__:
            print("Attribute: '{}' defined in {}".format(attr, base))
```

Now, this follows the `mro` tuple (equal to `(__main__.D, __main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, object)` in this specific case) and yields a similar output:

```
Attribute: 'another' defined in <class '__main__.C'>
Attribute: 'bar' defined in <class '__main__.A'>
Attribute: 'foo' defined in <class '__main__.A'>
Attribute: 'biz' defined in <class '__main__.B'>
```

Comment: Would this work if say, the method is in a grandfather class? Great grandfather? Further up the tree?

Comment: @JonathanStein: You'd want to switch from `__bases__` (which only looks at the immediate parents) to `__mro__` for iteration (which contains the [C3 linearization of the inheritance chain](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Comment: Yup, as @ShadowRanger said, change `__bases__` to `__mro__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do checking through the parent classes as determined by the method resolution order and checking the members of each parent class:

```
for i in C.__mro__:
  if 'bar' in i.__dict__:
    print 'bar is in class ' + i.__name__
```

So, given the following classes definitions:

```
class A(object):
  def foo(self): pass
  def bar(self): pass

class B(object):
  def biz(self): pass

class C(A,B): pass
```

Running the above code will give

```
bar is in class A
```